# C# expose events with properties

Tags: c#, events, properties

I need to expose an event of an instance of a class using a property from a different class.

If I expose an event defined in `MyClass` with a property defined in the same `MyClass`, so that the event works like a backing field, everything is fine:

```
private event EventHandler<EventArgs> _somethingHappened;
public EventHandler<EventArgs> SomethingHappened
{
     get => _somethingHappened;
}
```

Could sound weird, but it might be useful for some reason.

But if I expose (in the same manner) an event defined in `AnotherClass`, accessed by an instance of that `AnotherClass`, as follows:

```
public EventHandler<EventArgs> SomethingStarted
{
    get => Instance.Started;
}
```

where `Instance` is the instance of that `AnotherClass` and `Instance.Started` is defined in `AnotherClass` as follows:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Started;
```

then I get the error: "The event can only appear on the left hand side".

I just don't get why the first case is allowed and the second is not, although they seem very similar.

Comment: If I wanted to do this I'd have an event on my own class that fired when the eventhandler on the class I was wrapping was called (I listen to the event, and I fire my own event when I detect the other event occurring)

Comment: Yes, interesting solution, I didn't think about it, since I was really stuck on that error. But could "fire and re-fire an event" bring to performance inefficiency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Events do not have getters nor setters, they only have `add` and `remove` accessors thus they cannot be used as properties.

By code `get => Instance.Started` you're trying to *get* the value of `Instance.Started` but there is no getter.

What you can do is make `SomethingStarted` also an event and override `add` and `remove` accessors to forward the value to the `Instance.Started` event:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SomethingStarted
{
    add => Instance.Started += value;
    remove => Instance.Started -= value;
}
```

This way any subscription to `SomethingStarted` would be "redirected" to `Instance.Started` without causing event to be *re-fired*.

Internally, this would be translated into something like:

```
public void add_SomethingStarted(EventHandler<EventArgs> eventHandler) {
    Instance.add_Started(eventHandler);
}

public void remove_SomethingStarted(EventHandler<EventArgs> eventHandler) {
    Instance.remove_Started(eventHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I marked this as accepted because it answers directly my question about the error.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to expose an event of an instance of a class using a property from a different class.

You shouldn't use events this way. Event should always be exposed as an `event`.
What you can do is to expose other class' event through your own class:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SomethingHappened
{
    add => Instance.Started += value;
    remove => Instance.Started -= value;
}
```

This way a subscriber will actually subscribe to the `Instance`'s event. You can wrap it to a method and re-fire an event to change the `sender`.

Comment: So it's more a problem of concept and correct use of the events. Thank you very much for your interesting answer, I understand events even better now.